# How to align a column of cells by a symbol

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, alignment, symbols

I'm trying to replicate a table format from a paper,

They have centre aligned the following cells by the ± symbol. I have searched online and only found aligning by decimal.

**Example input (1 column, 3 rows)**

```
536 ± 49.2
68.4 ± 48
502.9 ± 39.4
```

**Desired output (1 column, 3 rows)**

```
  536 ± 49.2
 68.4 ± 48
502.9 ± 39.4
```

I would be very grateful for any advice!

****Edit**** For those interested the Table I'm trying to copy is here http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10681-012-0690-4#page-1

****Solved*** See reply below by Alex Frolov for solution!
The alternative is to make 3 columns that appears to be 1 column but that wasn't suitable for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create the helper column with the following formula
`=REPT(" ",10-FIND("±",A1))&A1`

where `A1` - your original string and `10` - the maximal number of characters before "±" in your data

Then apply the monotype font (e.g. "Courier new") to this column

Comment: Thank you very much this is perfect, after a lot of forum searching and couldn't find a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to split the data into three columns. Right align the first, left align the last.

If your data is in column A, col B could be

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND(" ± ",A1)-1)
```

And col D

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ± ",A1)+3,99)
```

Leave col C simply "±" and hide col A.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I could use multiple columns but for this I needed it to be 1 column each.

Comment: You could add an additional column that concatenates the new B,C,D and center that. Just giving outside of the box suggestions.